# Can a glass screen protector reduce the impact on a phone?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, material-science, glass

Glass screen protectors supposedly protect your phone from impact. A youtube comment by McZidanne sums up this idea pretty clearly:

> The thing about tempered glass cover isn't the protection they offer. It's the fact that they give in easier than the screen, so when a surge of energy is released into the phone as a result of a fall, the tempered glass absorbs that energy and protects the phone from having to absorb it.

However logically with my limited understanding of Physics this does not seem to be a phenomenon I can understand. A thin hard object shouldn't be able to reduce the force applied on the screen nearly at all, or can it? At least a plastic screen protector is soft, and can thus (theoretically) change the angle of the force partially (even if too insignificantly to be useful), but something hard as glass seems to me to be even less capable of protecting against impact. Am I missing something about the material properties of tempered glass?

Comment: I hope this question falls under the "Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena" on-topic category.

Comment: And secondly, I do get why tempered glass is used over normal glass, and I get that a glass screen protector can give a phone a more premium feel when the only goal is to protect against scratches. The thing I am asking about is just the relation between hardness and ability to protect from drops. (Same thing as hard cases for example)

Answer (score 1):

> The thing about tempered glass cover isn't the protection they offer. It's the fact that they give in easier than the screen, so when a surge of energy is released into the phone as a result of a fall, the tempered glass absorbs that energy and protects the phone from having to absorb it.

To say that the glass "gives in easier" is a bit misleading, but this is the basic concept. To protect the real screen of the phone, one wants a protector that will absorb the shock from any impact, rather than that shock breaking the real screen of the phone. So, we want a material that is hard and tough so that it will withstand large impacts (i.e. dropping the phone from your hip on concrete). Tempered glass is harder and tougher than plastics, see figure 1 in the first citation below.

> A thin hard object shouldn't be able to reduce the force applied on the screen nearly at all, or can it?

Yes, certainly! Appearances can be deceiving in nature, eh? For instance, a given weight of spider silk is stronger than steel!

Regular glass has [about the same](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.232.7029&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (see fig. 1) fracture toughness as commercial plastics. But tempered glass has a much higher fracture toughness than regular glass (that's the whole point of it), especially if they're [chemically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempered_glass#Manufacturing) tempered rather than thermally tempered. Note that glasses generally have much larger hardness than plastics as well, so toughness is the dominant contributor to the material's ability to survive a fall, no matter how it falls.

So, tempered glass has a larger resistance to fracturing (it is tougher) than plastic, meaning that the tempered glass can absorb more energy from an impact than the plastic. Thus, for a given impact force, the tempered glass is less likely to break than the plastic.

Comment: Absorbed energy is energy turned into heat?

And let's put it this way, I would expect a cushion in front of a display to help a lot more than a piece of glass... why does it matter at what point the glass fractures (unless it actually changes a non-negligible amount of impact force into heat)? Isn't the only important thing how "squishy" it is to allow changing the angle of the impact force partially? 

Comment: No, changing the angle of the impact force is not the only important thing. IF it was, then at what angle would you prefer to hit the ground at after falling from the top of a building? If wrapped in squishy stuff, the impact will go thru the squishy stuff and hit you. Something hard will absorb the impact. And it matters at what point the glass/plastic fractures, because your question is about which one is better to survive under impact, which the impact will cause the material to fracture.... So you want the material that's least likely to fracture.

Comment: @DavidMulder Are you considering something hitting the phone directly into the screen, or see you thinking about the case where you drop your phone and it hits the ground on it side or it's corner?

Comment: Ummm, what's all this about plastic vs. glass? Phone screens are glass, Gorilla Glass normally.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Yes, but the question from the OP is about screen protectors over the real glass of the phone itself

Comment: Yeah, but the OP is about "Glass screen protectors". He mentions plastic ones in contrast.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the property of a glass protector, most relevant to the protection of the screen (as opposed to protecting itself from scratches or breakage) and separating it from a plastic protector is its stiffness or rigidity, i.e., its ability to resist deformation.

As pointed out by JMac in the comments, this (stiffness) helps spread an impact over a large area reducing the stress on the screen.

An easily deformable plastic protector would pass a localized stress right through and this is exactly the kind of a stress that is likely to break the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The things is there are several type of glass and the intensity up to which they can absorb the energy is also different. Whenever a phone hits the ground the tamper gets in contact first and uses up the impact energy into breaking itself (the stronger the hit the more it breaks, depends on angles too - spread of cracks) and the remaining energy is then transferred to the original phone screen (now they all have gorilla glass). It happened a lot to me my tamper breaks but screen remains intact.

Answer (score -2):

How much energy can a material absorb (per unit volume) is given by the material's toughness, which is the area under the strain-stress curve up to fracture:

[image]

Comment: Is there supposed to be more to this?  Currently this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I'm responding to this: "The thing I am asking about is just the relation between hardness and ability to protect from drops." - How much of that energy generated by the free fall can the glass absorb, well, you'll have to look for the corresponding stress curve and compute the toughness.

Comment: Even the question you're talking about, they asked about hardness and you answered about toughness.  Those are not the same.  I also don't think you're even touching the core of the question, which is why one might choose a glass protector over a plastic one.

Comment: Well, the hardness wont have any effect on how much energy the material can absorb. About the "core of the question", you can look for the strain-stress curve of any plastic and see the difference on the amount of energy that can be absorbed.

Comment: And toughness doesn't explain why someone would choose a glass screen over a plastic one.  I think OP may actually have been onto something when he specifically mentions hardness; because that will have a relationship to how the impact can actually propagate through the phone.  I suspect that the glass is able to absorb the energy more uniformly across it's surface compared to a plastic screen.  Regardless, this definitely isn't an answer to what was asked.

Comment: Why would hardness have anything to do with it? Hardness is a material's ability to withstand friction....

Comment: @N.Steinle The internal reaction to hitting something.  A softer material would localize the impact a lot more than a hard material; which would change how the energy can spread out through it.  Also, I wouldn't really call hardness the materials ability to withstand friction.  That doesn't clearly describe a lot of the ways we analyze hardness.  You might be thinking of scratch hardness; but that's not the only type.

Comment: @JMac Hardness is relevant when something sharp is hitting or scraping the object... that's not what's happening when you drop a phone. Something very hard can break almost instantly on impact, for instance ceramic or untempered glass. We want a material that will not fracture upon impact.

Comment: I'm not voting to delete this because although I believe that it doesn't answer the question very specifically, it does seem to add some slightly relevant information based on the interpretation of the question. [Review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/230059)

Comment: @N.Steinle I don't think we want a material that will not fracture on impact.  The quote that OP is referencing in the question suggests the exact opposite. "_The thing about tempered glass cover isn't the protection they offer. It's the fact that they give in easier than the screen, so when a surge of energy is released into the phone as a result of a fall, the tempered glass absorbs that energy and protects the phone from having to absorb it._" The hardness plays a factor here.  Say you drop your phone and it lands face first on the ground; but there's like a pebble or something. (continued)

Comment: @JMac In figure 1 of this article, you see that various types of glass have various toughness, but they're all harder than plastics. Hardness is not what determines whether or not the plastic or glass case is better for impacts... Toughness is what separates them. Maybe someday someone will invent a plastic that is very very tough.... Someday. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.232.7029&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @N.Steinle If you have a softer cover that still undergoes plastic deformation; you will have a localized indent that may go right into your real screen.  If you have a harder glass cover; the impact will be less localized.  This may result in breaking the tempered glass screen protector; but the energy would ultimately be dissipated along a larger area of your real screen, sacrificing the protector to keep your screen intact.

Comment: So, even if I admit that hardness does play a role here, all glass has higher hardness (larger strength) than plastics. So a material with high toughness and high hardness (like tempered glass) wont feel the "less localized" impact as you say due to the high toughness